# Playframework 1.2.4 Evolutions not working

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am unable to generate 1.sql:

play evolutions or  play evolutions gives the same output

```
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! master-4877ea8, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Connected to jdbc:mysql://localhost/artoodb2?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
~ Application revision is 0 [da39a3e] and Database revision is 0 [da39a3e]
~
~ Your database is up to date
~
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave it unmodified then and create desired evolution in 2.sql

Comment: Do I create an empty 2.sql manually? and then evolutions will pickup?

Comment: Ayyy... my fault it should be: Just create new file in path: _/db/evolutions/2.sql_ , later 3.sql, 4.sql etc. each file need to contains only differences between previous state and new required state. And yes _Just create new file_ means literally that you need to create the file in your favourite editor. You should also check the [documentation of evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/evolutions)